# Spring Throwing 404 After nginx Call

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, nginx

My Vue app connects to two backends. Only one is using SpringBoot, which is not working with nginx. My nginx.conf.template contains:

```
location /apcc {
   proxy_pass ${APCC_BACKEND_URL};
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   proxy_redirect ${APCC_BACKEND_URL} $scheme://$http_host/;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
   proxy_read_timeout 20d;
   proxy_buffering off;
}
location /rmer {
   proxy_pass ${RMER_BACKEND_ENDPOINT};
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   proxy_redirect ${RMER_BACKEND_ENDPOINT} $scheme://$http_host/;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
   proxy_read_timeout 20d;
   proxy_buffering off;
}
```

the calls for the working have on the Ajax url:

```
/apcc/spd/sensitivePart/findAll/
```

and for the not working url:

```
/rmer/getAllMvsVDetailC
```

When seeing the front-end logs for calls I see the following:

```
172.25.2.172 - testuser [10/Jul/2023:20:33:07 +0000] "POST /apcc/user/loginAuthenticator/doLogin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 474 "https://apcc-dev-frontend.dal2a.ciocloud.nonprod.intranet.ibm.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
172.24.2.70 - testuser [10/Jul/2023:20:33:20 +0000] "GET /rmer/getAllMvsVDetailC HTTP/1.1" 404 146 "https://apcc-dev-frontend.dal2a.ciocloud.nonprod.intranet.ibm.com/rmer" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

The first call being for the working backend call and the second for the not working one.

Where you can see the "rmer" is being added twice, in the the call itself and on the server.

```
"GET /rmer/getAllMvsVDetailC HTTP/1.1" 404 146 "https://apcc-dev-frontend.dal2a.ciocloud.nonprod.intranet.ibm.com/rmer"
```

Why is this happening for one nginx location but not for the other?

Answer (score 0):

PubNub's Vue SDK is no longer officially supported: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks#call-for-contributions